# Можно ли вывести математические формулы в python?

Tags: python, kivy

Мне нужен модуль, позволяющий преобразовывать код python в математические формулы, например из 2**2 в 2². Нужно, чтобы было преобразование в дроби и корни. Мы работаем в KivyMd. Заранее спасибо

Comment: LaTeX вам в помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого можете воспользоваться библиотекой matplotlib. Она умеет рендерить LaTeX.

Вот простой пример:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Добавляем формулу
formula = r'$2^2 = 2 + 2 = 4$'
plt.text(0.01, 0.8, formula, fontsize=50)

# Прячем оси
fig = plt.gca()
fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

# Сохраняем как картинку
plt.savefig('filename.png')
```

Вот результат:

[image: Вот результат]

Разумеется, вы можете рисовать формулы любой сложности.
После этого можно просто использовать полученное изображение

Comment: А, ну вот и ответ :)