# Красивый вывод случайно сгенерированной формулы в Python

Tags: python, вывод, формулы, sympy

Задача: необходимо сгенерировать уравнение со случайными параметрами (они будут достаточно сложными по структуре) и сохранить его в виде рисунка. С генерацией уравнения я справился, а с красивым (наиболее близким к рукописной математической записи) выводом - нет. Как можно это сделать?

Есть фрагмент кода

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import sympy
import random
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
Ratio=random.randint(-30,30)*x**2+random.randint(-30,30)*x+random.randint(-30,30)
plt.text(0.01, 0.8, Ratio, fontsize=9)
fig = plt.gca()
fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.savefig('filename0001.png')
```

Comment: Функция всегда квадратичная или может быть что-то более сложное?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1080034 отвечает на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Собственно, я брал код оттуда, но у меня иной вывод, некрасивый. Функции будут более сложными, в основном показательными, с дробями и корнями в степени

Comment: matplotlib или внешний сервис с поддержкой LaTex https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1242076/420098

Comment: Я попытался сделать через matplotlib, но у меня выдается само символьное выражение, а не его красивый вид

Comment: Может, зайти по-другому? Как перевести символьное выражение в сырую строку в Python?

Comment: напишите желаемый пример, что должно быть на выходе ?

Comment: У меня выводится результат типа 15*x**2+30*x+25. А должна быть хорошая формула без знаков умножения и с квадратом в верхнем индексе

Comment: stroka='15*x**2+30*x+25'
stroka=stroka.replace('**2', '\u00b2').replace('*','')    
не предлагать ?

Comment: Наверное, нет. Потому что степени могут быть любыми (+ дроби, + может быть выражение в степени), и каждый раз искать код соответствующего символа - очень сильно усложнять

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать возможности LaTeX. Его можно интегрировать в python

Comment: Интегрировать не надо, SymPy умеет выводить LaTeX.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]